# Как выбрать следующий элемент после удаления из сортированного списка?

Tags: c#, wpf

ListView заполняется сортированными данными из CollectionViewSource, которые в свою очередь берутся из ObservableCollection. Примерно так:

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsSortByName" Source="{Binding CountryData}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSortByName}} SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStuff}"/>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы после удаления элемента выбирался следующий элемент в сортированном списке? То есть если есть

```
 index id  name
 0     1   1
 1     3   3
 2     4   4
```

Добавляем 2

```
 index id  name
 0     1   1
 3     5   2 - выбранная строка
 1     3   3
 2     4   4
```

Удаляем 3 5 2 из ObservableCollection.

```
CountryData.Remove(item);
```

Как сделать строку 1 3 3 выбранной?

Добавил SelectedItem, но это не решает проблему.

Кусок, отвечающий за удаление:

```
    foreach (CountryModel item in CountryData.Where(s => s.Selected))
    {
         countriesToDelete.Add(new Tuple<int, CountryModel(countryData.IndexOf(item), item));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countriesToDelete.Count; i++)
    {
        Country countryToDelete = DatabaseModel.SelectByPK<Country>(countriesToDelete[i].Item2.DbId.ToString());
        DatabaseModel.Delete(countryToDelete);
        CountryData.Remove(countriesToDelete[i].Item2);
    }
```

Вот если бы кто подсказал, как вот здесь

```
  s => s.Selected
```

Сделать что-то типа

```
  s => s.Selected + 1 (я знаю, что так нельзя)
```

Тогда можно было бы просто делать последний элемент в списке на удаление SelectedStuff и не удалять его.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection сам по себе не позволяет работать с текущим элементом. Для этого вам необходимо добавить отдельное свойство в свою ViewModel (или что у вас содержится в ListView.DataContext). 
Например так:

## XAML окна

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsSortByName" Source="{Binding CountryData}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSortByName}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Height="30" Width="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

## Немного Code Behind для минимально требуемой связки с ViewModel

```
    private readonly ViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this.vm = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.vm.DeleteCurrentItemExecute();
    }
```

## ViewModel с ObservableCollection и SelectedItem свойствами

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model selectedItem;

    public Model SelectedItem
    {
        get { return this.selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, this.selectedItem)) return;
            this.selectedItem = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> CountryData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            new Model {Index = 0, Id = 1, Name = "1"},
            new Model {Index = 3, Id = 5, Name = "2"},
            new Model {Index = 1, Id = 3, Name = "3"},
            new Model {Index = 2, Id = 4, Name = "4"},
        };

    public void DeleteCurrentItemExecute()
    {
        var indexOfSelectedItem = this.CountryData.IndexOf(this.SelectedItem);
        this.CountryData.Remove(this.SelectedItem);
        if (this.CountryData.Count == 0)
        {
            this.SelectedItem = null;
        }
        else
        {
            var newIndexOfSelectedItem = indexOfSelectedItem > this.CountryData.Count - 1 ? this.CountryData.Count - 1 : indexOfSelectedItem;
            this.SelectedItem = this.CountryData[newIndexOfSelectedItem];
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

## Модель для ваших данных

```
public class Model
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Но это не то.

Comment: Допустим, я сохраняю 3 в переменной. Проверяю. Новый индекс - 2, то есть последняя строка в отсортированном списке, а не следующая с индексом 1. Как-то неожиданно было, что комментарий отправляется по Enter.

Comment: Можете подробнее расписать описанный сценарий? Что значит "сохраняю 3 в переменной", что "проверяете" и почему "новый индекс - 2"?

Comment: Все по вашему ответу. indexOfSelectedItem - 3.

Comment: Количество элементов в списке после удаления - 3

Comment: Прошу прощения, количество элементов - 2

Comment: То есть, в newIndexOfSelectedItem - получается 2, индекс последнего элемента в списке

Comment: А хотелось бы - 1, следующий за удаленным элементом

Comment: Я в вопросе немного подробностей добавил.

Comment: Все равно не понял. Алгоритм такой: 1. На форме выбираем элемент на первой позиции(indexOfSelectedItem = 1, считая с нулевого) - это "new Model {Index = 3, Id = 5, Name = "2"},"; 2. Удаляем этот элемент из коллекции (первый элемент удалён, остальные сдвинулись влево). 3. Говорим что текущий выбранный элемент это тот, который сейчас в коллекции первый (т.к. indexOfSelectedItem = 1), то есть new Model {Index = 1, Id = 3, Name = "3"};   Разве это не ожидаемое поведение?

Comment: Индекс это не свойство модели, это индекс элемента в ObservableCollection, отсортированной CollectionViewSource.
CollectionViewSource индексы не меняет, а сортирует что есть.
Во вьюмодели я работаю с ObservableCollection.